# Why won't my function return the correct outputs?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program for class that requires me to do the following. Load a file of words into a vector of strings, allow user to enter a word to search, perform a sequential search, sort the words using Selection Sort, and finally perform a Binary Search.

I managed to get the entire program working as intended except for the Binary Search. For some reason I cannot understand, my Sequential Search function displays all the information correctly while the Binary Search function only displays the initial cout.

Thank you for all the help!

Here is a copy of the current output running my program:

> ```
> Enter the word to search for:
> YELL
> YELL was found successfully after 407 comparisons!
> Perform selection sort...
>
> Perform a binary search using selection sorted vector...
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

The code for my program (I know no one likes the use of using namespace std but I am required to do so for my class):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void loadWords(vector<string>& words); // load unsorted words from file to vector of strings.

int sequentialSearch(vector<string>& words, string targetWord, int& count); // Perform sequential search and keep track of how many comparisons have happened.

void selectionSort(vector<string>& wordsSorted); // Perform the selection sort on the words.

int binarySearch(vector<string>& wordsSorted, string targetWord, int& count); // Perform binary search and keep track of how many comparisons have happened.

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    vector<string> wordsSorted;

    loadWords(words);
    wordsSorted = words;
    string targetWord;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter the word to search for: " << endl;
    getline(cin, targetWord);

    sequentialSearch(words, targetWord, count);

    selectionSort(wordsSorted);

    binarySearch(words, targetWord, count);

    return 0;
}

void loadWords(vector<string>& words)
{

    ifstream inFile("unsortedBog.dat");

    string word;

    while (inFile >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    inFile.close();
}

int sequentialSearch(vector<string>& words, string targetWord, int& count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
    {
        count++;
        if (words[i] == targetWord)
        {
            cout << targetWord << " was found successfully " << "after " << count << " comparisons!" << endl;
            return i;
        }
    }
    cout << "After performing " << count << " comparisons, " << targetWord << " could not be found." << endl;
}

void selectionSort(vector<string>& wordsSorted)
{
    cout << "Perform selection sort... \n" << endl;
    int min = 0;
    string min1;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordsSorted.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (wordsSorted[i] < wordsSorted[min])
        {
            min = i;
        }
        min1 = wordsSorted[i];
        wordsSorted[i] = wordsSorted[min];
        wordsSorted[min] = min1;

    }
}

int binarySearch(vector<string>& wordsSorted, string targetWord, int& count)
{
    cout << "Perform a binary search using selection sorted vector... \n" << endl;

    int first = 0,
        last = wordsSorted.size() - 1,
        mid,
        position = -1;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        int i = 0;
        count = i++;
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        if (wordsSorted[mid] == targetWord) // If value is found at mid
        {
            found = true;
            position = mid;
            cout << "The target word was located successfully after performing " << count << " comparisons.";
            return position;
        }
        else if (wordsSorted[mid] > targetWord) // Lower half
            last = mid - 1;
        else if (wordsSorted[mid] < targetWord) // Upper half
            first = mid + 1;
        else
            cout << "After performing " << count << " comparisons, the target word could not be found.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary search requires a sorted array.

Your `selectionSort()` falls far, far short of its task of sorting the array.

The only thing it does is that it searches the array for the word that should be the first word in the sorted list, moves it to the first position in the array, and proclaims "mission complete". The rest of the array remains unsorted.

And since `binarySearch()` assumes that the array is sorted, it goes completely off the rails.

P.S. Just to make things worse, `selectionSort()` fails to search the entire array in the first place. It doesn't look at the last element in the array. If the lexicographically first word is in the last element in the array, it won't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I had a feeling my for loops where a little off. At least I understand where I need to start with fixing this mess, I appreciate it!

Comment: @DiddyMoe, also note that you'll need to actually pass the "sorted" vector into `binarySearch()`.  In the above code, you're just passing a copy of the original unsorted vector.  `wordsSorted` is not declared as a reference; it's its own separate instance (initialized by a copy of `words`).  Also, consider passing the vectors by `const&` into the functions that don't modify them.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I used C++, but this is how I solved the problem. Excuse the inefficiency of my code, as I was just going for a general solution.

A few problems I noticed was that:

Your selection sort wasn't working. From what I remember, most of these inefficient sorting algorithms require two loops, one to keep track of where you are in the array, and the other to compare the current element to all the other elements of the array.

You were passing in the wrong vector into the binarySearch function. Instead of passing the sorted vector from the selectionSort function, you passed the "words" vector instead. This meant that even if selectionSort was working, you still wouldn't have had the right answer.

Inside your binarySearch function, your count doesn't work because "i" is inside the while loop. This means that each time the loop executes, "i" and "count" both reset to zero. To prevent this, put "i" outside the loop so that it can actually increase itself each time.

I tested this with a list of four elements, and it seemed to work for me. If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to ask. It was fun coding in C++ again.

Also, I don't know how your "count" is supposed to work here. If you count the successful comparison as one comparison, then "count" should start at one. If the successful comparison doesn't count, then count starts at zero.

```
void selectionSort(vector<string>& wordsSorted)
{
cout << "Perform selection sort... \n" << endl;
int min = 0;
string min1 = wordsSorted[0];
int lowestIndex = 0;
bool isBigger = false; // I used a boolean because I was kinda lazy. This checks if a swap is needed so a swap doesn't happen every run through.

for (int i = 0; i < wordsSorted.size(); i++)
{
    min1 = wordsSorted[i];
    for(int j = i + 1; j < wordsSorted.size(); j++) // Second for loop to find the smallest element 
    {
        if (min1 > wordsSorted[j])
        {
            min1 = wordsSorted[j]; // Keeping track of the minimum word found so far
            lowestIndex = j; // Keeping track of where the smallest element is in the array.
            isBigger = true; // Noted that a swap is needed
        }

    }
    if (isBigger) // If the boolean changed, then swap the words.
    {
        string temp = wordsSorted[i];
        wordsSorted[i] = min1;
        wordsSorted[lowestIndex] = temp;
        isBigger = false;
    }

}
}    

int binarySearch(vector<string>& wordsSorted, string targetWord, int& count)
{
cout << "Perform a binary search using selection sorted vector... \n" << endl;

int first = 0,
    last = wordsSorted.size() - 1,
    mid,
    position = -1,
    i = 0;

bool found = false;

while (!found && first <= last)
{
    //int i = 0;
    count = i++;
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (wordsSorted[mid] == targetWord) // If value is found at mid
    {
        found = true;
        position = mid;
        cout << "The target word was located successfully after performing " << count << " comparisons.";
        return position;
    }
    else if (wordsSorted[mid] > targetWord) // Lower half
        last = mid - 1;
    else if (wordsSorted[mid] < targetWord) // Upper half
        first = mid + 1;
    else
        cout << "After performing " << count << " comparisons, the target word could not be found.";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I really appreciate it! I love the comments you made, it helped me understand my own program with a lot more depth. Crossing my fingers I can finish/ fix it before sleeping.

Comment: Why does the loop need to be performed twice? I thought the loop is going to find the smallest element(s) then loop again and swap the smallest elements until everything is ordered correctly. Wait a second... Is that the reason why we need a loop within a loop?

Comment: Yes, so basically, the inner loop iterates through the vector to find the smallest element, and the outer loop keeps track of where the element is supposed to go.